# FOSUserBundle: Registration redirect if logged in

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I was wondering what would be the best method to redirect a user who is ALREADY LOGGED IN if they try and access the registration page.

I would prefer a method that does not require me overriding the registration controller simply to implement a login check & redirect.

I looked at the registration initialization event but I don't know how to initiate the redirect since there doesn't seem to be a way to set the event response via the UserEvent class.

Thanks

Comment: Overriding the controller would be the simplest way. Implementing a listener of some sort would probably be more difficult and convoluted.

Comment: I personally find using event listeners much neater (and simpler).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use something like the following..

```
namespace Acme\UserBundle\EventSubscriber;

use FOS\UserBundle\Event\GetResponseUserEvent;
use FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserEvents;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContextInterface;

class FOSUserSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    protected $router;

    protected $securityContext;

    public function __construct(
        UrlGeneratorInterface $router,
        SecurityContextInterface $securityContext
    )
    {
        $this->router = $router;
        $this->securityContext = $securityContext;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_INITIALIZE  => 'forwardToRouteIfUser',
        );
    }

    public function forwardToRouteIfUser(GetResponseUserEvent $event)
    {
        if (!$this->securityContext->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED')) {
            return;
        }

        $url = $this->router->generate('acme_the_route_to_redirect_to');

        $response = new RedirectResponse($url);

        $event->setResponse($response);
    }
}
```

With

```
parameters:
    acme_user.subscriber.fos_user.class: 
            Acme\UserBundle\EventSubscriber\FOSUserSubscriber

services:
    acme_user.subscriber.fos_user:
        class: %acme_user.subscriber.fos_user.class%
        arguments:
            - @router
            - @security.context
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_subscriber
```

Comment: I did not realize that GetResponseUserEvent could be used! Thank you.