# How to forbid access for authorised users in Symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm a beginner in Symfony2. Now I try to finish writing authorisation, using FOSUserBundle.
I have a problem, that authorised user can access to log in page or register page. Can I change this in configs or I have to check it in the controller?
Thank you

PS I mean such part in security.yml:

```
access_control:
    - { path: /new, role: ROLE_USER }
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

Comment: Why would this be a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve it by creating an event listener which will [hook into the FOSUserBundle controllers](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/controller_events.html). For registration you could use [fos_user.registration.initialize](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/FOSUserEvents.php#L129) event. In your listener you could check if user is already authenticated, if yes then redirect to whatever route you like (e.g. to homepage). See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24310419/fosuserbundle-registration-redirect-if-logged-in) to see the example.

For login route (`/login`) you could override the default FOSUserBundle [SecurityController](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Controller/SecurityController.php) and check there if user is authenticated and do the redirect. See this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20191919/1316350).

Comment: Nice :)
Thank you, it's that I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use expressions like here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/access_control.html#book-security-allow-if.

Expression could be:

```
"is_anonymous() and and not is_remember_me() not is_fully_authenticated()"
```