# Disable (login/register) for already 'logged in' users in FOSuserBundle

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I just need to Disable (login/register...) for already 'logged in' users in FOSuserBundle

for example : 'alexa' is logged in , so she can't open (login/register) pages, she will be forwarded to her profile .

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FOSUserBundle: Registration redirect if logged in](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24310419/fosuserbundle-registration-redirect-if-logged-in)

Answer (score 0):

Just override login/register controllers and write some logic in them. 
More about how to check if user logged in: [How to check if an user is logged in Symfony2 inside a controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10271570/how-to-check-if-an-user-is-logged-in-symfony2-inside-a-controller)

More about FOS controllers overriding: http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/overriding_controllers.html